# error in missingno module import in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, missing-data

Getting error in missingno module import in Jupyter Notebook . It works fine in IDLE . But showing "No missingno module exist" in Jupyter Notebook . Can anybody tell me how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 3):

Installing missingno through anaconda solved the problem for me

Comment: Oh . I'm able to run it now . . Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This command helped me:
`conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 missingno`
 You have to make sure that you run Anaconda prompt as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this command too:

```
pip install missingno
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1- Open Anaconda Navigator
2- go to the third option on the left (CMD.exe prompt)
3- launch it
4- paste this line "conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 missingno"
5- its gonna tell you to agree on the intallation process just type in Y

and there you go hopefully that will work :P